# Is it possible to use Active directory without a trust relationship for FreeIPA passwords?

Tags: linux, active-directory, freeipa

I am looking to integrate FreeIPA with an Active Directory environment that I do not have full control over and most likely will not be able to get a trust relationship setup with my FreeIPA install.

My needs for FreeIPA are simple, just need to use it for LDAP password authentication. I'd like to keep the same usernames and passwords that are setup in Active Directory and have FreeIPA talk to AD's Kerberos for authentication.

Does anyone have any guidance on how to set this up?

Comment: Ummmm... that's what the trust is for!

Comment: Can you please explain? Please forgive me I am a bit green in this area.

Comment: I think my situation is similar and so I'll give my explanation of what I think is at issue here.  I have a semi-isolated lab with AIX, Linux and Solaris systems.  The lab can not get to the corporate network.  There is a pair of Linux servers that are on both networks to provide proxy service for the lab.  I'd like passwords in my lab AIX/Linux/Solaris systems to link to the Active Directory on the corp network, but have no contact with those people.  Can I set up a trust without involving the Active Directory administrators?  (Or should I just use AD for simple LDAP authentication?)